# AzureAppServiceSettings@1 - Conflict - Parameter with name Version already exists

Tags: yaml, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines

I have an Azure DevOps Pipeline below:

```
...

steps:
- task: AzureAppServiceSettings@1
  displayName: 'Update App Service app settings'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: ${{parameters.azureSubscription}}
    appName: ${{parameters.appName}}
    resourceGroupName: ${{parameters.resourceGroupName}}
    slotName: ${{parameters.slotName}}
    appSettings: |
      [
        {
          "name": "${{parameters.settingName}}",
          "value": "${{parameters.buildNumber}}",
          "slotSetting": false
        }
      ]

...
```

When running my pipeline, I'm getting the error:

> ##[error]Error: Failed to update App service 'my-application-blue' application settings. Error: Conflict - Parameter with name Version already exists. (CODE: 409)

The parameter `Version` indeed already exists on my app configuration, but what's odd is that I have the same parameter on other apps, and the same step runs fine on those apps.

All I could find when researching, was that another deployment could be ongoing, but that's not the case, I restarted the app and retried the step and the same error persists.

How can it fix it or find the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was happening because a config key with value `VERSION` already existed.

My guess is when the task is deciding whether to create or update a value, it doesn't find an existing key, but trying to add the same key under a different casing causes the issue.

Updating the existing key from `VERSION` to `Version` fixed the issue and the step executed normally.

Comment: This solved my problem right on time. I had renamed all the keys from the release to lower-case, but there are some required keys that needed to be on the config on Azure else the deployment will timeout. Those keys were in the default upper-case.